# Matlab gui 3 2D views of 3D data. Non cardinal image planes. Maintain interactive speed?

Tags: matlab

I deal with 3D medical images. (CT, MRI, SPECT, PET, ...)
I've found that Matlab is fast enough for displaying, panning, zooming, and interrogating values for the cardinal orthogonal planes in 3 views (transverse, sagittal, coronal). I accomplish this by creating a surface object with texture mapping.

However, I want to take this one step further and be able to display an arbitrary plane through the volume. So, if I set an arbitrary plane on one view, the other views will update and be orthogonal.

So, now instead of indexing into a volume (e.g. Arr(:,:,i)) which you can do in the cardinal planes I have to perform 3 interpolations of about 512x512 each and update the surfaces.
This doesnt provide the type of interactive speed I want - its not interactive for rotations. If I downsample to 64x64 its reasonable, but thats not really an option. I've profiled my code and the interpolations and setting the surface CData take up most of the time.

Am I going about this the wrong way? 
Is it possible (and would it be faster) to load a volume, rotate arbitrarily with the camera and set near and far clipping planes to display the noncardinal image plane?

Comment: I'm not an expert in 3D, but have you tried the 'slice' command in MATLAB? I think it does what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rotating the 3D volume first and then going through the cardinal planes is a bit faster?

http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/08/17/spatial-transformations-three-dimensional-rotation/